# OR condition in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Is this code:

```
IIF(Fields!XXX.Value = "0" OR ISNOTHING(Fields!XXX.Value), TRUE, FALSE)
```

The same as:

```
IIF(Fields!XXX.Value = "0", TRUE, IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!XXX.Value), TRUE, FALSE))
```

Will the first method work or only the second method for SSRS?

Comment: Was there some reason you couldn't find out by testing it?

Comment: both equivalent and will "work" but what is your desired outcome?

Answer (score 1):

Both are equivalent and will work